# Sources of funding to curate exisiting datasets?

Tags: releasing-data, historical

At my institution (a large land-grant US University), there are some long term research programs that would be of great value to the scientific community if the data were curated and published in an online database or repository.

The datasets (long term experimental studies of agricultural cropping systems) fit in the domains of agriculture, geophysics, ecology, biology.

These datasets are currently in a combination of spreadsheets and notebooks, with very heterogeneous formatting. I am thinking of a budget on the order of ~$150k per dataset, primarily to fund an 18mo postdoc.

Are there sources of funding available for such work, in which the primary output is a dataset?

Although such work could be 'built in' to hypothesis-driven grants, I am curious if there are sources of funding specifically for curation of existing data. The applications of such data could be described to justify the work (with many letters of support from end users).

Comment: Googling "curation funding" (no quotes) yields several good resources and some major projects and funding institutions. Interestingly, if you google "data curation funding" (no quotes), the results are poorer.

Comment: @BarryCarter I did but don't find any sources of funding. Could you provide more details about what you found that would address my scenario?